# После настройки редиректа с http на https все страницы сайта редиректят на /index.php

Tags: .htaccess, https, ssl, редирект

Здраствуйте!
После попытки настроить редирект с http на https все страницы сайта начали перенаправляться на /index.php

При этом проверка редиректа показывает такую ситуацию [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться, что в htaccess не так.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 

RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)admin/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).gif
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).svg
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![^/]+\.[^./]+$
RewriteRule (.+)/? $1/index.html [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*\.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blank.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*\.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*\.jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*\.jpeg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*\.gif
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*\.htc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*\.png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*\.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*\.swf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forum/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/gallery/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/com/scr/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/*/upload/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/datxml.xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots.txt
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/cars.zip

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^en/com/([0-9a-zA-Z_.,/-~Е]+?)$ com/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^ru/com/([0-9a-zA-Z_.,/-~Е]+?)$ com/$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Решить проблему получилось, добавив строку в начале файла .htaccess:

SetEnvIf X-SSL-Emu on HTTPS=on

И все заработало, как нужно!!!!